# Maya Python - how to iterate through list and attach objects

Tags: python, loops, maya

I am creating a list based on user selection and want for each selected item in the list (object, vertex etc.) create a locator at that items world position:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
selection = mc.ls(sl=True)

for each in selection:
    newLoc = mc.spaceLocator()
    mySelPosition = mc.xform(selection, q=True, ws=True, t=True)
    mc.move(mySelPosition[0], mySelPosition[1], mySelPosition[2], newLoc)
```

This doesn't work when selecting objects (say two spheres) and it just creates a locator at the origin.

When selecting multiple vertices, it creates as many locators as selected list items, but they are all created at the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I follow,  but I think your problem is in line 6,

```py
mySelPosition = mc.xform(selection, q=True, ws=True, t=True)  # your line
mySelPosition = mc.xform(each, q=True, ws=True, t=True)  # correct line
```

try this:

```py
import maya.cmds as mc
selection = mc.ls(sl=True)

for each in selection:
    newLoc = mc.spaceLocator()
    mySelPosition = mc.xform(each, q=True, ws=True, t=True)
    mc.move(mySelPosition[0], mySelPosition[1], mySelPosition[2], newLoc)
```

Comment: That was it... thank you! Ooof - I spent so long staring at this and it just didn't click.

Just to clarify. I wanted to be able to select any number of objects (or component like a vertex or edge) and create a locator at that point.